# CustomHook: Avoid using the old Scope in Callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to `React` and I created a minimal test application to illustrate the `scope` problem.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function useCounter(topic, defaultMsg) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(defaultMsg);

  const increment=() =>{
      console.log("increment from " + message);
      setMessage(message+1);
  }

  return [message, increment];
}

export default function App() {
  const [counter, incrementCounter] = useCounter("anyData", 0);


  return (
    <div>
      <p>you clicked: {counter} times</p>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("sending ");
          incrementCounter(counter); //works 
          incrementCounter(counter); //doesn't work because using the old scope
        }}
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output

```
App.js:10 increment from 0
App.js:10 increment from 0  //should be 1
App.js:27 sending 
App.js:10 increment from 1 
App.js:10 increment from 1  //should be 2
```

If the button is pressed, then `incrementCounter` is called twice. Expected behaviour: Each click increments the counter by 2. However, it doesen't because the `useCounter` hook seems to use the old value of message. So each clicks increments the counter by 1. I know why that doesn't work, I don't know how to fix that.

How would you solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is state update calls in event handlers are batched and hence multiple calls to setState without using the callback approach here will not update the value correctly

Think of the code

```
      incrementCounter(counter); 
      incrementCounter(counter);
```

as

```
 setMessage(message + 1);
 setMessage(message + 1);
```

Now both these calls are merged and the final change that will be applied to setState is `message + 1` which `1`.

Also state updates are async and are not reflected immediately

If you change the setMessage implementation to [`function state update`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setMessage(prevMessage => prevMessage+1);
```

You will see the output you expect because in this case batching isn't performed by react and the state will be incremented twice. However you will still see the same output in console due to the async nature of setState

[Sample DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-meitner-9hvgx)

Comment: thanks, can you provide a reference for the setMessage(prevMessage => prevMessage+1); concept?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates